# PHP SSL "older" stream sockets close unexpectedly

Tags: php, sockets, ssl, stream

I am developping a SSL websocket server, PHP 8.2.

I can accept SSL conections with no problem.

Issue is:

Connection A, then B then C then D are accepted.

When conection C closes (clients make the disconection, not the server), then conections A and B are unexpectedly closed (but not D).

An "fread" on stream socket A or B will raise this warning:
fread(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac in....

Reading on socket D will be still ok.

This occurs only with SSL conections, not with unencrypted conections.

In fact, all sockets opened BEFORE the closing socket are also closed.

Sample of my code :

```
$transport = 'tlsv1.3';
$ssl = ['ssl' => [
'local_cert'  => $sslCert,       
'local_pk'    => $sslKey,    
'disable_compression' => true,
'verify_peer'         => false,
'allow_self_signed'         => true,            
'ssltransport' => $transport,
] ];
    
$context = stream_context_create($ssl);
        
$socketS = stream_socket_server(
'ssl://0.0.0.0:'.$wssPort,
$errno,
$errstr,
STREAM_SERVER_BIND|STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN,
$context
);



....

do {
$tCpy = array($socketS);
$retSocket=stream_select($tCpy, $null, $null, 20, 0);
if ($retSocket>0 ) {
    // New conection
    stream_set_blocking($socketS, true);
    $cliSocket = stream_socket_accept($socketS,5,$ip);


        ...

        $pid = pcntl_fork();
        
        if ($pid>0) {
         //  OK
           echo("Fork ok");
           continue;
       } else if ($pid < 0) {
          echo("Error fork");
          continue;
       } else break;
}
} while(true);

// Do something with newly connected client...
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems I found the issue, so I post the reply if it can help others:

The key is that the encryption must be started after the fork statement.

So, here is the code:

```
$transport = 'tlsv1.3';
$ssl = ['ssl' => [
  'local_cert'  => $sslCert,       
  'local_pk'    => $sslKey,    
  'disable_compression' => true,
  'verify_peer'         => false,
  'allow_self_signed'         => true,            
  'ssltransport' => $transport,
]];
        
$context = stream_context_create($ssl);
     
// Change from ssl:// to tcp://    
    
$socketS = stream_socket_server(
  'tcp://0.0.0.0:'.$wssPort,
  $errno,
  $errstr,
  STREAM_SERVER_BIND|STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN,
  $context
);

....
    
do {
  $tCpy = array($socketS);
  $retSocket=stream_select($tCpy, $null, $null, 20, 0);
  if ($retSocket>0 ) {
    // New conection
    stream_set_blocking($socketS, true);
    $cliSocket = stream_socket_accept($socketS,5,$ip);
    
    ...
    
    $pid = pcntl_fork();
            
    if ($pid>0) {
      //  OK
      echo("Fork ok");
      continue;
    } else if ($pid < 0) {
      echo("Error fork");
      continue;
    } else break;
  }
} while(true);
    
// Do something with newly connected client...
// Here we start the crypto using the context 
    
stream_socket_enable_crypto($cliSocket, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_SERVER);
```